# DB2/400 SQL subqueries

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I want to make sure that warehouses C and D are both in the same City.

Is there simpler way to do this?

Table:

```
City Warehouse
1      A        
1      B
2      C
2      D 
3      E
3      F
```

SQL:

```
WITH subquery AS(
  SELECT DISTINCT WHM.City FROM WHM WHERE  
  WHM.Warehouse = 'C' or WHM.Warehouse ='D'
  GROUP BY WHM.City 
  ORDER BY WHM.City ) 
SELECT count(*) FROM subquery
```

If response = 1, then True

Comment: This isn't a sub query, it is a common table expression. a subquery would be in the from or join clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a minor improvement on what you already have, but you could select the distinct count and avoid the unnecessary subquery:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT City)     -- returns 1 for a single shared city
FROM WHM
WHERE Warehouse IN ('C', 'D');
```

Note that `GROUP BY` is not needed as we want the distinct count across the entire table.

Comment: I think this is more than a minor improvement. It's much simpler and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Direct query

```
select (select distinct 1 from WHM w2 where w2.city=w1.city and w2.Warehouse='D') response
from WHM w1
where w1.Warehouse='C'
;
```

returns 1 or null

`distinct 1` - for case where more than 1 Warehouse='D' in City (if possible).